# Where do I get the value for `shopOrigin` when using Shopify app bridge?

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-app-bridge

Throughout the documentation for the new App Bridge, Shopify refers to the `shopOrigin` value and how it's used to configure the Provider from `app-bridge-react` but they never specify how to get this value?

[image]

The react app is loaded inside of an iframe and the src includes the `shopOrigin` value as a query string param called `shop`, but when I try the following code I get the error `window is not defined`:

```
const params = queryString.parse(window.location.search);
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  shopOrigin: params.shop,
};
```

1) Why would I be getting `window is not defined` in javascript code running in a browser?! This makes no sense to me
2) If this value can be read from of the provided libraries such as `@shopufy/app-bridge-react` please tell me how

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using a library tailored specifically to Shopify, you have to manually save the shop origin during OAuth authorization.

Hopefully this [Shopify tutorial](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/get-and-store-the-shop-origin) is of some assistance

Comment: I have the shopOrigin stored, the problem is server side rendering/initial props and getting that value into the client code. Their examples are not very thorough and don't really explain how anything works, which is frustrating for someone new to NextJS and react ssr.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree! I was working on a Spring Boot Java app and getting it to provide info to the React app was a mess. I ended up having the server populate a Javascript var in index.html, which the react app would then have access to. Not a great solution but it worked

Comment: this answer does not help. The OP clearly has a nextjs server set up, with shopify `shopOirign` retrieved from oauth flow, how do you pass it to the react App.
@SomethingOn have you solved this somehow ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is the need for shopOrigin, if you just wanted to go to admin section of the shop from client side you can use [Redirect](https://shopify.dev/tools/app-bridge/actions/navigation/redirect) in app bridge. otherwise you can store the shop detail on server during auth process and create a get api to retrive the details on client side as needed.

Answer (score -1):

The shopOrigin is available within your browser cookies.

If you followed the Shopify development for react and Node.js, you should already saved this after the Shopify authentification.